# I can't find the file I copied with the COPY command in dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm learning Docker. I created a dockerfile like this.

```
FROM alpine:3.10.3

WORKDIR /dev/mirai
COPY mirai-console-wrapper-0.3.0.jar .
```

Then i build it with command

```
docker build -t mirai:0.0.1 .
```

It seems like I successfully built it.

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  10.04MB
Step 1/3 : FROM alpine:3.10.3
 ---> 965ea09ff2eb
Step 2/3 : WORKDIR /dev/mirai
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d3af4049af4a

Step 3/3 : COPY mirai-console-wrapper-0.3.0.jar .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 56df1145ecab
Successfully built 56df1145ecab
Successfully tagged mirai:0.0.1
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have
 '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
```

But when i run this image

```
docker run -it mirai:0.0.1
```

I can't find my copied file mirai-console-wrapper-0.3.0.jar

```
/dev/mirai # ls
/dev/mirai #
```

There is nothing in the folder mirai.
I just want to copy the file in my docker image.

Comment: `/dev` often contains a virtual filesystem autopopulated with available device files.  Does using another directory work (even just `/mirai` in the root of the container filesystem)?

Comment: oh thanks a lot, it work!!!  It's time for me to learn linux now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/dev` directory tree often uses a special filesystem that contains automatically-generated special device files; you shouldn't expect to be able to store general-purpose files there.

If you can install your application into "normal" directories (for example, put the main program into `/usr/local/bin`) that will be the easiest to run.  If not, using a path directly in the filesystem root directory is common; use something like `/mirai` for your application, or something generic like `/app`.